# Angular App not updating when source files have been changed

Tags: angularjs, xampp

I'm trying to develop my first Angular application, however quite often, when I change the source files, the app isn't updating.

I am using Firefox and the Xampp stack. If I change, for example, a view or even a controller, when I refresh my page, I am not seeing the updated changes. I just opened Chrome and it is showing the updated changes.

Is there some sort of caching going on, or any gotchas that I should know about?

Answer (score 4):

Keep your dev-tools open, right-click on the refresh icon, and click 'empty cache and hard reload'. That should do it.

Comment: Firefox just doesn't want to refresh! I can see the button in Chrome, but not in Firefox. I did a `Ctrl` + `F5` and also a `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `R` in Firefox and it's still showing the old version. I've literally got Chrome and Firebox side by side on the same local URL and both showing different things.

Comment: got the same issues, found a fix yet?

Comment: I am using chrome and just clearing my cached files and images fixed the problem, maybe do something similar in FireFox?